# Is PyDev compatible with Java 9?

Tags: java, compatibility, pydev, java-9

According to [PyDev's documentation](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html):

> **PyDev requires Java 8** and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) in order to run and only supports Python 2.6 onwards. [...]

The documentation states that the installation will silently fail if Java 8 is not installed. However, I have the more recent Java 9 installed.

Is PyDev compatible with Java 9? Or will I need to reinstall Java 8?

Comment: Why don't you just give it a try?

Answer (score 0):

PyDev is currently only tested with Java 8, so, that's what's recommended.

Still, it should work with Java 9 too (as java is usually backward-compatible). If something doesn't work, please create a bug report (see: http://www.pydev.org/about.html for links).